# Angular: how to inject multiple instance of abstract service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-directive

I am a bit new to Angular and trying to understand code written by a senior dev. pardon me if I do not follow with the standard communication practice and words.

I have an abstract class `abstractDatService` with an abstract method `getEntities()` which have the implementation classes as `impl1` and `impl2`

Implementation class looks like :

```
@Injectable()
export class impl1 extends abstractDatService{
  
  private entities: Modal[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      type: "a",
      name: "a1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      type: "a",
      name: "a2"
    }
  ];

  public getEntities(): Observable<Modal[]> {
    return of(this.entities);
  }
}
```

Now, in my module, I am trying to inject the service as :

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: abstractDatService,
      useClass: impl1
    },
    {
      provide: abstractDatService,
      useClass: impl2
    }
  ]
```

In this case, when I try to get the entities they return me the entities from `impl2` class only and not of `impl1`

I want the implementation to return both.

Can anyone help me figure out this?

EDIT :

To elaborate

I have the component where I am displaying the data in a way that

```
HEAD1
Data from impl1 // this line is a common component in which there is a ngFor on observable returned.

HEAD2
Data from impl2 // this line is a common component in which there is a ngFor on observable returned.
```

The common component is the one that displays Data from impl1 and Data from impl2 Both

Comment: Please elaborate. what do you mean with you want them both? Do you mean you want the injected service to be a combination of both, so that getEntities returns the elements from both? Or do you mean that you want to inject an both anywhere?

Comment: Yes I want to inject in a way that I get data for both modal impl1 and impl2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments

> Please elaborate. what do you mean with you want them both? Do you mean you want the injected service to be a combination of both, so that getEntities returns the elements from both?

> Yes I want to inject in a way that I get data for both models impl1 and impl2

You need to change 2 things.

1st: Your provider definition to include `multi: true`

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: AbstractionService,
      useClass: Impl1Service,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: AbstractionService,
      useClass: Impl2Service,
      multi: true,
    }
  ]
```

2nd: Handle the multi Injection with array

```
 constructor(@Inject(AbstractionService) impls: AbstractionService[]) {
    const obs$ = impls.map(impl => impl.getEntities());

    combineLatest(obs$).subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

Check the same on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pwysue?file=src/app/app.module.ts