# Dependency Injection via Abstract class/Interface to an Array in Angular

Tags: angular, spring, typescript

In Spring, we have a useful feature where we can get the instances of all the implementations of an Interface in a List. The code for that is like below:

```java
public interface Vehicle {
    void runs();
}

@Component
public class Car implements Vehicle {
    public void runs(){
        // some implementation
    }
}

@Component
public class Bike implements Vehicle {
    public void runs(){
        // some implementation
    }
}

@Component
public class SomeService {

    @Autowired // dependency injection
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

    public void otherMethod() {
        for(int i = 0; i < vehicles.size(); i++) {
            vehicles[i].runs();
        }
    }
}
```

This way we can execute multiple functions without even touching existing methods. Can we achieve such type of an implementation in Angular as well.

Comment: i think even in spring that is true for beans, which is services in this case not components i believe?

Comment: you can do this kind of stuff with services as they are auto initialized not components.

Comment: @AakashGarg Yes it works for beans annotated with `@Component` / `@Service` in Spring.

Comment: @AakashGarg `you can do this kind of stuff with services as they are auto initialized not components` in Angular did you meant? Could you please post me any online resource or tell me what this concept is referred to in Angular.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63724435/10982972